# SMS Text Messaging using dot net and SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: sms

I need the ability to text someone using a dotnet application and SQL Server 2008 R2 database.  Do I need a GMS modem that has SMS compatibility? Is there a software package that is open source I could use with these two technologies or is there a way I can accomplish this task without having to incur a monthly service fee?

Answer (score 0):

Some cell carriers provide the ability to pass an email through to an SMS.  In that case, it would be possible to send the email form either the .NET app, or from the SQL server.

You might make use of an [SMS Gateway](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SMS_gateway):

> "Many SMS gateways support media conversion from email and other
>   formats."